# predictions of a trained model

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pytorch, python-imaging-library

I am running the code in Jupyter Notebook and facing this error "AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'read'". I have searched it a lot but everyone has different error.

```
model = models.resnet18(pretrained = True)
num_ftrs = model.fc.in_features
model.fc = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, 4)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load('4_stage_model.pt'))
model.eval()

classes = ('1', '2', '3', '4')
class_probs = []
class_preds = []
with torch.no_grad():
    for data in testloader:
        images = data
        output = model(images)
        class_probs_batch = [F.softmax(el, dim=0) for el in output]
        _, class_preds_batch = torch.max(output, 1)

        class_probs.append(class_probs_batch)
        class_preds.append(class_preds_batch)

test_probs = torch.cat([torch.stack(batch) for batch in class_probs])
test_preds = torch.cat(class_preds)
```

I also have a calss of CustomDataset. The code is

```
class CustomDataSet(Dataset):
def __init__(self, csv_file, root_dir, transform):
    self.root_dir = root_dir
    self.transform = transform
    self.dataframe = pd.read_csv(csv_file)

def __len__(self):
    return len(self.dataframe)

def __getitem__(self, idx):
    if torch.is_tensor(idx):
        idx = idx.tolist()
    img_path = self.dataframe.iloc[idx, 15]
    image = Image.open(img_path).convert("RGB")
    tensor_image = self.transform(image)
    return tensor_image
```

The error is:

```
File~/.conda/envs/flowering/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/Image.py:3098,inopen(fp,mode,formats)
3096
fp. seek(0)
3097 except (AttributeError, io.Unsupportedoperation):
-
3098
fp
= i0.BytesI0(fp. read() )
3099
exclusive_fp = True
3101 prefix = fp. read(16)
AttributeError: 'numpy. int64' object has no attribute
*read"
```

Comment: please review [ask] and [mre]. remove that screenshot. replace with the contained _text_. you can [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

[Image.open()](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.open) requires a filename, not a numpy array.